# change dimensions of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

as it is I have a `GridView` with 2 colums (consent -> checkbox) and the name of the profile. it has 12 rows. I have to make the GirdView **3x4** or **4x3**. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` displays data in 2D table one row for each record and one cell for each property so to achieve **3x4** or **4x3** you can use `ListView` check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474696/showing-images-in-gridview-as-block-items) and this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Either Datalist Control or ListView Control to Show Data in Multiple Columns

you can use Datalist for showing data in 4X3 format as follows:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" Width="100%">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server"></asp:CheckBox></td>
        <td><%#Eval("name") %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

We can use RepeatColumns="3" property of Datalist to show Data in 3 Columns.

May this answer help you.